# How can I create a calc mixin to pass as an expression to generate tags?

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a sass stylesheet in which I wish to use the `calc` element to dynamically size some content. As the `calc` element has not been standardized, I need to target `calc()`, `-moz-calc()`, and `-webkit-calc()`.

Is there a way for me to create a mixin or function that I can pass an expression to so that it will generate the required tags that can then be set as a `width` or `height`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It would be a basic [mixin with an argument](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html), thankfully the expressions are not browser-specific within the supported scope:

```html
@mixin calc($property, $expression) {
  #{$property}: -webkit-calc(#{$expression});
  #{$property}: calc(#{$expression});
}

.test {
  @include calc(width, "25% - 1em");
}
```

Will render as

```html
.test {
  width: -webkit-calc(25% - 1em);
  width: calc(25% - 1em);
}
```

You may want to include a "default" value for when calc is not supported.

Comment: This is perfect I had no idea you could pass a property to a mixin but it makes sense now

Comment: Don't just go around adding prefixes willy-nilly.  Opera doesn't support `calc()` at the moment, but when it does, it's fairly likely to do it without prefixes.

Comment: If you are using [Bourbon](http://www.bourbon.io), there is a [calc mixin](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_calc.scss) built right in.

Comment: I don't understand why property needs to be escaped as well? I'd also add `-moz-calc` as value. It's still supported by ~ .6% of users refering to caniuse.com

Comment: @VolkerE.: this behaviour is according to spec - variables in selectors and property names have to use [interpolation syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use something like Autoprefixer in your workflow, instead of using mixins only for browsers vendor prefixes?

Comment: Thanks to this function you should be able to use variables in the calc() css function e.g. `@include calc(width, '100% - '$variable);`

Comment: @Fleuv you can use interpolation in a "normal" rule without a mixin: `width: calc(100% - #{$variable});`

Comment: Bourbon link provided above is not working anymore, here is link to source code for the [calc mixin in the Bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/v4-stable/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_calc.scss)

Answer (score 10):

Compass offers [a shared utility](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/shared/#mixin-experimental-value) to add vendor prefixes for just such an occasion.

```
@import "compass/css3/shared";

$experimental-support-for-opera: true; // Optional, since it's off by default

.test {
  @include experimental-value(width, calc(25% - 1em));
}
```

Comment: Does not allow for variables.  What about: ``@include experimental-value(width, calc(100% - ($sidebarWidth + $padding)));``?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but does this work? `@include experimental-value(width, calc(100% - #{$sidebarWidth + $padding}));`

Comment: The [shared utility](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/shared/#mixin-experimental-value) has been deprecated from compass.

Comment: Indeed it has! That's probably because `calc()` has hit the mainstream: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 4):

Using calc can be accomplised pretty easily using the unquote feature:

```
$variable: 100%
height: $variable //for browsers that don't support the calc function  
height:unquote("-moz-calc(")$variable unquote("+ 44px)")
height:unquote("-o-calc(")$variable unquote("+ 44px)")
height:unquote("-webkit-calc(")$variable unquote("+ 44px)")   
height:unquote("calc(")$variable unquote("+ 44px)")
```

will render as:

```
height: 100%;
height: -moz-calc( 100% + 44px);
height: -o-calc( 100% + 44px);
height: -webkit-calc( 100% + 44px);
height: calc( 100% + 44px);
```

You can also try creating the mixin as suggested above, but I do mine slightly different:

```
$var1: 1
$var2: $var1 * 100%
@mixin calc($property, $variable, $operation, $value, $fallback)
 #{$property}: $fallback //for browsers that don't support calc function
 #{$property}: -mox-calc(#{$variable} #{$operation} #{$value})
 #{$property}: -o-calc(#{$variable} #{$operation} #{$value})
 #{$property}: -webkit-calc(#{$variable} #{$operation} #{$value})
 #{$property}: calc(#{$variable} #{$operation} #{$value})

.item     
 @include calc(height, $var1 / $var2, "+", 44px, $var1 / $var2 - 2%)
```

will render as:

```
.item {
height: 98%;
height: -mox-calc(100% + 44px);
height: -o-calc(100% + 44px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% + 44px);
height: calc(100% + 44px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it:

```
@mixin calc($prop, $val) {
  @each $pre in -webkit-, -moz-, -o- {
    #{$prop}: $pre + calc(#{$val});
  } 
  #{$prop}: calc(#{$val});
}

.myClass {
  @include calc(width, "25% - 1em");
}
```

I think this is more elegant way.