# Tool to process CSS file converting unsupported styles to web-kit equivalent?

Tags: css, webkit

Are there any tools out there that can process a CSS file, inserting -webkit equivalents for styles that aren't 100% supported across the board?

I'm using calc() in my CSS which isn't supported across all browsers.  Instead I have to use -webkit-calc() for safari etc.

I'd like a tool that will insert -webkit into the CSS for styles that aren't supported 100% across the board, or to be able to specify the target browsers/versions and have the tool work out whether it needs to be inserted or not.  Presumably the tool would have to know what styles were supported in which version of which browsers.

Comment: rather than adding a script to your page, like prefix-free, you can use SASS to achieve this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826064/calc-element-in-sass-css

Comment: Yeah, it looks like SASS/LESS will be the solution.  I like the idea of prefix free, but it isn't primetime ready.

Comment: prefix-free should be used only for dev environments (even then, SASS eliminates any need for it) - you don't want to add another request to a production site for something that can be handled directly in your CSS, and that is cached for further requests. If you haven't yet worked with Sass, I strongly recommend taking a look at Sass Bourbon for managing prefixes on a range of properties - I've adapted Bourbon according to my needs: https://github.com/larrybotha/styleguide/tree/master/css/sass/modules/utilities - but Bourbon as it is is a great solution, and not as heavy as Compass.

Comment: See this : http://prefixr.com/index.php

Comment: @MilchePatern doesn't do calc() (my test case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for http://lesscss.org/?

The dynamic stylesheet language.
LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions.
LESS runs on both the server-side (with Node.js and Rhino) or client-side (modern browsers only).

**[EDIT]**

After answering, i found this website http://prefixr.com/index.php where they use a script to reformat css declarations. Maybe you could study this one.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

Comment: I think I am, but it doesn't look ready for primetime yet.  My only test case so far is calc() and the TestDrive page they have doesn't convert it to -webkit-calc for desktop Safari 6.  Not a great sign!