# Can I subtract a pixel width from a page width percentage?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

Basically, I want a centre div with a fixed width, and two side panels that will scale with the page-size.

The complication is I want to add some content to the side panels, so (margin: 0 auto;) on the centre div won't work.

This is what I've tried, but the width element for Side Panel doesn't process. It works if I change 100% to a pixel value.

**HTML**

```
<div class="SidePanel"></div>
<div id="MainPanel"></div>
<div class="SidePanel"></div>
```

**SCSS**

```
/* Variables */
$MainPanelWidth: 800px;

.SidePanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: ((100% - $MainPanelWidth) / 2);
}

#MainPanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: $MainPanelWidth;
}
```

Thanks.

**Answer:**

Thanks for the help guys! I got the rest of what I need to know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function).

- Calc works out the equation.
- Variables can be used by interpolating them like this
  #{$MainPanelWidth}

**SCSS**

```
.SidePanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc((100% - #{$MainPanelWidth}) / 2);
}

#MainPanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: $MainPanelWidth;
}
```

Thanks to web-tiki and François Wahl.

Comment: Thanks guys!. This as achieved what I was looking for. It seems that calc doesn't accept variables though? 

Is there any way to work the variable in?

Comment: This will probably help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826064/calc-element-in-sass-css

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()` in your CSS, like this:

```
.SidePanel {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - (800px / 2));
}

#MainPanel {
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
}
```

or using your SASS/LESS (not sure which it is) syntax:

```
/* Variables */
$MainPanelWidth: 800px;

.SidePanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - ($MainPanelWidth / 2));
}

#MainPanel {
    height: 100%;
    width: $MainPanelWidth;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVa9w/) - Using calc();

---

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get calc to process with the variable though. I'm using the Sassy Studio extention for VS as my preprocessor. Should it work?

Comment: @user2078938: I don't use any CSS preprocessors so I don't really know how SASS would apply it. - Seems you got it figured out if I see your last edit correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc()` ([MDN calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) css function like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/HL3ty/)**

```
.SidePanel {
    float:left;
    background:gold;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(50% - 400px);
}

#MainPanel {
    float:left;
    background:red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
}
```