# mixin variables not parsed correctly with Saas in visual studio 2015

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, sass

Use the sass in an application vs. 2015, and use the mixin like this:

```
@mixin getHeightDueToElements($percent, $numberOfElements) {
  height: calc($percent/$numberOfElements);
  margin: auto;
}
```

Then when I call:

```
@include getHeightDueToElements(100%, 3);
```

But unfortunately in the css seems to me this way:

```
height: calc($percent/$numberOfElements);
margin: auto;
```

that is the mixin variables are not recognized!

I installed the various libraries but it seems to go well no (Compiler Web, Web Essential) ...

Help

Answer (score 1):

You should use  `height: calc(#{$percent}/#{$numberOfElements});`
According to: 
[Sass Calc](https://coderwall.com/p/qac-og/sass-css3-calc-mixin)

You can see this question too: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826064/calc-element-in-sass-css)